# Resizing and creating a responsive logo in NavBar with CSS and ROR

Tags: jquery, html, css, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap

I have an image that I am trying to resize on the navbar of my Ruby on Rails app. It is currently too big to serve as a navbar logo and is not responsive.

The image size is currently: 333 x 333px

How can I dramatically adjust image size so it fits and is responsive?

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation">
<div class="container">
<div class="container-fluid">
  <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
  <div class="navbar-header">
   <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-ex1-collapse">
      <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
     <span class="icon-bar"></span>
     <span class="icon-bar"></span>
   </button>
    <%= link_to  image_tag('Cool_logo.png'), root_path, class: "navbar-brand" %>
 </div>
   <%= link_to  "Sub Zero", root_path, class: "navbar-brand" %>
 </div>

<div class="collapse navbar-collapse navbar-ex1-collapse">
  <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
    <li><%= link_to 'Home', root_path %></li>
    <li><%= link_to 'About', about_path %></li>
    <li><%= link_to 'Contact Us', contact_path %></li>

    <% if user_signed_in? %>
      <li><%= link_to 'New Listing', new_pin_path %></li>
      <li><%= link_to "Account Settings", edit_user_registration_path %></li>
      <li><%= link_to "Log Out", destroy_user_session_path, method: :delete %></li>
    <% else %>
     <li><%= link_to "Register", new_user_registration_path %></li>
     <li><%= link_to "Log In", new_user_session_path %></li>
  <% end %>

  </ul>
</div>
```

Here is some of the CSS; I'm using bootsrap as well.

```
 @import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Arimo:400,700);

 $body-bg: #bdc3c7;
 $font-family-sans-serif: 'Arimo', sans-serif;
 $navbar-default-link-color: white;
 $navbar-default-bg: #2c3e50;
 $navbar-default-link-hover-color: #ecf0f1;
 $jumbotron-bg: #2c3e50;
 $btn-default-bg: #2980b9;
 $btn-default-color: white;
 $btn-success-bg: #1abc9c;
 @import 'bootstrap';

.jumbotron {
  margin-bottom: 0px;
background-image: url(http://i.imgur.com/7KqYuZU.png);
background-position: 0% 25%;
background-size: cover;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
color: white;
  text-shadow: black 0.3em 0.3em 0.3em;
}

 .center {
 text-align: center;
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a max-width to ensure that the image does not display larger than the size that you choose.

```
.navbar-header .navbar-brand{
    max-width: 200px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old question, but I went through the same issue today. 
One should add "img"

```
.navbar-brand img
{
    max-height: 100%;
}
```